# Error Installing Apache-Airflow on Window os

Tags: apache-spark, airflow

I am using pyspark

spark 2.4.4 and Pycharm
Python: 2.7

Please help me how can i do Airflow set up in **window OS** for Spark.
i am using pycharm to build spark application.

when i tried to install airflow package through pycharm, i am getting error as

```
File "C:\Users\Edward\AppData\Local\Temp\10\pycharm-packaging\dumb-init\setup.py", line 95, in run
        cmd = compiler.linker_exe + [f.name, '-static', '-o', os.devnull]
    AttributeError: MSVCCompiler instance has no attribute 'linker_exe'
    ----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: 'C:\Users\Edward\PycharmProjects\DataClean\venv\Scripts\python.exe' -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'

C:\\Users\\Edward\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\10\\pycharm-packaging\\dumb-init\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'

C:\\Users\\Edward\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\10\\pycharm-packaging\\dumb-init\\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' 
install --record 

'c:\users\Edward\appdata\local\temp\10\pip-record-ntk3mx\install-record.txt' --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers 

'C:\Users\Edward\PycharmProjects\Data\venv\include\site\python2.7\dumb-init' Check the logs for full command output.
```

Please help me, if someone can share Airflow set up in detailed.

Answer (score 0):

You can install Airflow into Windows 10 using Docker or Ubuntu WSL:

1) Docker is a tool for creating and managing “containers” which are like little virtual machines where you can run your code. There is a Airflow image ready to install:

- [Dockerfile of apache-airflow for Docker's automated build](https://github.com/puckel/docker-airflow)
- [Getting Started with Airflow Using Docker](https://towardsdatascience.com/getting-started-with-airflow-using-docker-cd8b44dbff98)

2) WSL (Windows Subsystem for Linux):

- [Apache Airflow Windows 10 Install (Ubuntu)](https://coding-stream-of-consciousness.com/2018/11/06/apache-airflow-windows-10-install-ubuntu/)